# Lync 2013 Click to Call base64 icon not saved when publishing a page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, html-editor

We have a SP2010 farm and about to enable Click 2 Call for the business

If we edit a publishing page and add a phone number the click 2 call icon appears after a second, however, when we publish the page the base64 string is omitted in the src attribute so after the number there's a blank icon with black border.

Now it shouldn't save the HTML at all should it so how can we disable this? We don't want this HTML added when we add a phone number (with no source for the image)

```
<a title="Call: +a number..." href="#" style="overflow:hidden;cursor:hand;border-top:medium none;height:16px;border-right:medium none;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap;right:0px;border-bottom:medium none; !important;float:none;left:0px;margin:0px;border-left:medium none;display:inline;top:0px;width:16px;bottom:0px"><img title="Call: +a number.. alt="" style="overflow:hidden;cursor:hand;border-top:medium none;height:16px;border-right:medium none;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap;right:0px;border-bottom:medium none; !important;float:none;left:0px;margin:0px;border-left:medium none;display:inline;top:0px;width:16px;bottom:0px"></a>
```

Any idea on how to stop this from happening when editing a page?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `base64 string is emitted` - does it make a sound? Or do you mean `omitted`? `If we edit a publishing page` - how? In the browser? Or in SPD? Page layout or content? `Now it shouldn't save the HTML` - Who is `it` and why not? What are you entering where and how? What would you expect to see? What do you see instead? -- And finally, please consider using CSS classes instead of inline styling. It helps with both readability and maintenance.

Comment: It obviously doesn't make a sound. Lync 2013 IE plugin adds the HTML I don't and that's the problem, I want to use Click to Call but how to add a phone number in edit mode of a page if SharePoint saves that garbage. Have you looked up Lync Click to Call?